# concatenate the columns using oracle 11g with '-'

Tags: sql, plsql, oracle11g, concatenation

The input looks like this, can someone please tell me how can I get the expected output. (for each unique customer id have to concatenate as start_term-end_term,rate;)

*Input:*

```
customer_id   start_term  end_term    rate 
-----------   ----------  --------    ----
101           61          72          0   
101           37          60          0  
101           24          36          0.9  
102           61          72          2.92  
103           24          36          2.92  
104           61          72          0  
104           37          60          0  
104           24          36          0
```

*Expected Output:*

```
customer_id rate  
----------- -------------------------
101         61-72,0;37-60,0;24-36,0.9  
102         61-72,2.92  
103         24-36,2.92  
104         61-72,0;37-60,0;24-26,0
```

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried anything, like googling for the solution?

Answer (score 1):

What you need here is [LISTAGG](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions089.htm#SQLRF30030) function.

You can try this:

```
SELECT customer_id, LISTAGG(start_term || '-' || end_term || ',' || rate, '; ')
       WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY rate) AS rate
  FROM table_name
 GROUP BY customer_id;
```

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for `listagg()`, something like this:

```
select customerid,
       listagg(start_term || '-' || end_term || ',' || rate, '; ')
           within group (order by start_term desc) 
from t
group by customerid;
```